# Cleaner way to attach event handler function and execute it on ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I have a page with button that modifies the layout (let's say checkbox that shows/hides a box) I end up writing following blocks of code:

```
$(function(){
    var advancedOptionsToggle = function() {
        var isChecked = $('#advanced-options-checkbox').checked;
        $('#advanced-options').toggle(isChecked);
    };
    advancedOptionsToggle();
    $('#advanced-options-checkbox').change(advancedOptionsToggle);
});
```

The reason is that my page content is dynamically generated on the server side, instead of rendered by JS on the client side, so the checkbox might already come checked.

It looks to like a common problem, so I believe there must be a pattern that solves it cleaner. Is there a jQuery function that can encapsulate it?

Comment: What `.show(isChecked )` is supposed to mean? I don't see any "overload" that accepts the first boolean argument.

Comment: I think this is about as simple as you can get. You already got rid of duplication by defining a named function.

Comment: It looks pretty good to me, as you have 2 ways to trigger your function, on load and an change. I don't think you'll find a cleaner way.

Comment: `.show(isChecked)` should be `.toggle(isChecked)`.

Comment: You can wrap the code with a custom jQuery plugin if you're planning to use this multiple times

Comment: @zerkms @Barmar I wrote it on the go, it's actually `.toggle(isChecked)`

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is certainly serviceable, however your question suggests that you may have several of these.  May I suggest creating a common pattern for this kind of usage, rather than resort to IDs?

```
$(function(){
    var toggleOptionCheck = function(el){
        var isChecked = $(el).is(':checked');
        $($(el).data('related')).toggle(isChecked);
    }
    $('.options-toggle').each(function(idx, el){
        toggleOptionCheck(el);
    });
    // Separate call for illustration/simplicity.
    $('.options-toggle').on('change', function(){toggleOptionCheck(this)});
});

<input type="checkbox" checked name="show_advanced" 
    class="options-toggle" data-related="#advanced-options" />
<div id="advanced-options" class="hidden-at-start"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple jQuery plugin like this to clean up the code a bit:

```
$.fn.advancedOptionsToggle = function(selector) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var isChecked = $(this).checked;

        $(this).unbind('change').change(function(){
            $(selector).toggle(isChecked));    
        });
    });
};

$(function(){
    $('#advanced-options-checkbox').advancedOptionsToggle('#advanced-options');
});
```